# asyncronous jQuery ajax-call blocking on "large" data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, blocking

I'm using jQuery.ajax (async) for posting "large" data. (for example a base64 encoded 4 MB image).
To show the progress to the user, I'm using xhr.

My problem is now, that the initialization of that call takes nearly 2 seconds before I get my first XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent.
Unfortunately it's not possible to show a ajax loader gif to the enduser in this time because it's freezing.

Is there any possibility to work around to show some visual response to the user or to lower the init time?

Example Code:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {console.log("xhr");
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        var firstcall = true;
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if(firstcall) {
                $('.progress').css("transition", "width .3s");
            }
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete, evt);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });

                if (percentComplete === 1) {
                    $('.progress').addClass("phide");
                }

                if(firstcall)  {
                    firstcall = false;
                }
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "path/upload.php",
    data: {data: base64image},
    async: true
});
```

Between the call of $.ajax and the first console.log("xhr") are in my example 1.3 seconds and between the xhr log and the first ProgressEvent again 0.4 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could simply show some ajax-loader.gif right before you execute the ajax request. Like on click on some button show the loader and then execute the ajax request. afterwards you can hide the loader in the success callback of your xhr request..$('yourButton').on('click', function(){$('.progress').show(); $.ajax..})

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately the gif itself stops "moving" as soon as the ajax call starts initializing. I think the reason for that is the large amount of data I want to pass, so I'm searching for a better way to achieve my goal in a user friendly way.

Comment: I think it stalls where you encode your file to base64 try encode in worker or upload blob

Comment: No, the encoding is already done, when the picture is added to the canvas. For the upload I have the canvas content in an object which I pass to JSON.stringify (which is quick and not blocking the browser). The blocking happens after calling $.ajax... and stops with the first ProgressEvent being fired.